# difference days between two dates

Tags: php, codeigniter, date, datediff

```
$diff = strtotime( date("Y-m-d",strtotime($row->Released_Date)) ) - strtotime( date("Y-m-d",strtotime($CommitmentDate)));
$days = intval(round($diff/86400));

$s = $days > 1 ? 's' : '';

$status = $days > 0 ? '<i class="fa fa-exclamation" original-title="Day'.$s.' lapsed - '.$days.'<br><i>'.date("F d, Y",strtotime($CommitmentDate)).'</i>"></i>' :
          $days = 0 ? '<i class="fa fa-check" original-title="RELEASED ON TIME<br><i>'.date("F d, Y",strtotime($CommitmentDate)).'</i>"></i>' :
        '<i class="fa fa-star" original-title="RELEASED BEFORE COMMITMENT DATE<br><i>'.date("F d, Y",strtotime($CommitmentDate)).'<br>'.$days.'</i>"></i>';
```

there's one **$days** that returns **zero** but it seems it didnt output an exact **zero** because i didnt see check sign...

i really dont know whats wrong...

i used

```
$days = intval(round($diff/86400));
$days = int(round($diff/86400);
```

i tried
    $days = intval($diff/86400);

its returning exact **ZERO** but i dont know why THE OUTPUT SAYING ITS LESS THAN ZERO

this is the output... the number on end is the output of **$days**...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1AIz.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhI3j.jpg)

PLEASE HELP....

Comment: What is the format of `$row->Released_Date` ?

Comment: its DATE TIME sir... and the commitment date is in DATE

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning `$days=0` you must use `==` operator to compare,

```
$days == 0 ? '<i class="fa fa-check" original-title="RELEASED ON TIME....
```

One more thing you can just use single time `strtotime` to get the difference like,

```
// no need to convert it in date then again in strtotime
$diff = strtotime( $row->Released_Date ) - strtotime($CommitmentDate);
```

**Updated,** you need to enclose the else part in `()` otherwise it will not return the result as expected like,

```
$status = $days > 0 ? '<i class="fa fa-exclamation" original-title="Day'.$s.' lapsed - '.$days.'<br><i>'.date("F d, Y",strtotime($CommitmentDate)).'</i>"></i>' :
      ($days == 0 ? '<i class="fa fa-check" original-title="RELEASED ON TIME<br><i>'.date("F d, Y",strtotime($CommitmentDate)).'</i>"></i>' :
  //--^ start enclosing here, with $days == 0 condition
    '<i class="fa fa-star" original-title="RELEASED BEFORE COMMITMENT DATE<br><i>'.
    date("F d, Y",strtotime($CommitmentDate)).'<br>'.$days.'</i>"></i>');
                                              // -- to here -----------^
```

Comment: i already did this sir, but it makes all output to CHECK...

Comment: Show me your `$CommitmentDate` and `$row->Released_Date`

Comment: sir I did this

     $diff = strtotime( date("Y-m-d",strtotime($row->Released_Date)) ) - strtotime( date("Y-m-d",strtotime($CommitmentDate)));

because the RELEASED_DATE is in date time... and the $commitmentDate is just a DATE

Comment: i update my question sir, i attached the images

Comment: @user6689924, try my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
$days = $interval->format('%a');
$daySec = $day * 86400;
```

Source : http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php